# WooCommerce visible/hidden price switch with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hide, price

First off: Iam only familiar with HTML and CSS. My PHP is reduced to max. "understand" it.
For my workplace Iam working on a WordPress with a WooCommerce ajax based b2b shop.

For our merchants, the prices of the products needs to be visible all the time. But if they choose to show the product to their customer, they don't want to show them the merchant prices, so they need a switch (button-like) to hide all prices. Basically a catalogue mode on a frontend button in the header e.g.
As soon as you press it, all prices should hide, even after you click on a product and you go to the detail page.

So I tried to use my basic php understandings and found this on google:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
```

I tied it to a button and it worked. The page reloads and after it, all prices are hidden. But it's just for that page. As soon as you go to the next page, reload it, or want to see the details, they're there again.
So I need a solution, to make this permanent **till** you press the button again. Ideally, the page doesn't even have to reload to hide the prices.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me here!

Comment: If you just need to hide those prices in the frontend, but not remove them from the source code (so that no customer could _ever_ find them, even if they had access and were able to use their browser dev tools), then you don’t necessarily need to hook into the page creation here, but you could hide them using JS &CSS. Then you would not need to re-load the current page either.

Comment: As for making this permanent, until the button is clicked again - you will have to store the current state somewhere then, so that you can read it back from there on every page load - like a cookie, or localStorage/sessionStorage.

Comment: This would be absolutely fine! Customers wont have any acces. I think I can add the CSS part myself with price classes and the hidden attribute. You have any idea how the JS part would work out for this button?